# Asp .Net MVC Dropdown

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, dropdown

I want to display range from 2000 to 2020, so I am using this:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.Year, Enumerable.Range(2000, 2020)
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString(),
    Value = x.ToString() }));
```

But it is displaying Range from 2000 to 4019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass count as second parameter here.

Learn more about [Enumerable.Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=net-5.0)

```
Enumerable.Range(2000, 21)
```